# weirdness: pointer address doesn't change but contents off by 1

Tags: c++, char, shared-memory, memory-address

I'm cross posting this, as it may be a Pd issue, but perhaps someone here knows why something like this would happen.

Short of it is, I've got a dll that I'm using in a program named Pd (puredata, for computer music). I've created an object called recordString, that I'm using in conjunction with the basic Pd API to create the dll that pd will read. All Pd needs access to are a few simple functions. I've made recordString part of the code that uses the Pd API.

Anyway, the recordString object contains a char* which I'm creating using new (I've also tried malloc). When I'm setting the value of the char* it sets correctly to HELLOWORLD. I'm outputting the address to make sure it stays where it should be.

I've confirmed that the value is as it should be, except later when I call a function to get the value of the char*, it has somehow been shifted by 1 byte.

Has anyone heard of a situation where a pointer will change addresses by a value of 1? Without being told to?

Anyway, here's the output, and following that is the code for the datarecord.cpp

```
string: HELLOWORLD
length: 10
address: 32774028
address-2: 32578488

calling postString
string: ELLOWORLD
length: 9
address: 32774028
address-2: 32578489
```

```
#include "m_pd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "datarecord.h"

using namespace std;

recordString::recordString()
    :name(NULL)
{
};

recordString::recordString(const char* sourceString)
{
    this->name = new char[strlen(sourceString)+1];

    post("-------- in string constructor -----------");
    post("address: %d", &this->name);
    strcpy(this->name, sourceString );
    post("copy: %s", this->name);
};

recordString::~recordString()
{
    //delete(this->name);
    delete[] name;
    name = NULL;

    //free(this->name);
};

recordString::recordString(const recordString & rhs)
{
    post("-------- in copy constructor -----------");
    post("source: %s", rhs.name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(rhs.name));
    post("\n");

    this->name = new char[strlen(rhs.name)+1];

    strcpy(this->name, rhs.name);

    post("copy: %s", this->name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(this->name));
    post("address: %d", &name);
    post("address-2: %d", name);
    post("\n");
}

recordString & recordString::operator=(const recordString &rhs)
{
    post("-------- in operator= -----------");
    post("source: %s", rhs.name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(rhs.name));
    post("\n");

    if(name!=NULL)
    {
        delete[] name;
    }

 //this->name = (char*) malloc((strlen(rhs.name))); 
    this->name = new char[strlen(rhs.name)+1];

    strcpy(this->name, rhs.name);

    post("copy: %s", this->name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(this->name));
    post("address: %d", &name);
    post("address-2: %d", name);
    post("\n");
}

int recordString::setString(const char * sourceString)
{

    post("-------- in setString -----------");
    post("source: %s", sourceString);
    post("length: %d", strlen(sourceString));
    post("\n");

    this->name = new char[strlen(sourceString)];
    strcpy(this->name, sourceString);

    post("copy: %s", this->name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(this->name));
    post("address: %d", &name);
    post("address-2: %d", name);
    post("\n");

    return (this->name == NULL);
}


void recordString::postString()
{
    post("string: %s", this->name);
    post("length: %d", strlen(this->name));
    post("address: %d", &name);
    post("address-2: %d", name);
    post("\n");
}
```

Comment: notice that your assignment operator overload should return something.

Comment: This is C++, not C (you have classes). In this case, using `std::string` will save you a lot of effort, and will probably speed up your code a little too.

Comment: To continue the comment by @Cameron, using the standard library for anything it can handle (generic collections, generic algorithms, and **lot** of other things) will simplify your life as a C++ programmer significantly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked with a few people, and the topic of word alignment and structure padding came up. The originally code for the structure was

```
typedef struct _something {
    t_object x_obj; // *this 
    recordString r;
} t_something
```

and for some reason the value of the pointer pointed to by r->name was being aligned to a 4-byte boundary. Don't know why exactly, but apparently had to do with structure padding. Did some testing to confirm this, and it was indeed being aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

I removed the recordString r from the struct, and placed it in the global context, and it no longer was affected by this alignment.

What is strange to me is that it was happening between calls, in different scopes, at different times, during runtime. I'm not too knowledgeable about compilers or packing/padding structs, but it seems dangerous for something like that to be happening at runtime.

Anyway, seems to be fixed now by removing the object from the struct.

Thanks! I'll leave this open for a while in case anyone has specifics to add regarding the alignment during runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you do not allocate enough memory for your string

```
this->name = new char[strlen(sourceString) + 1];
```

The `+ 1` is needed for the nul terminator that C style strings have.

Other errors are:

Using `delete` not `delete[]` (`new[]` should be paired with `delete[]`).

Your default constructor leaves `name` uninitalised.

Your assignment operator leaks memory since it never frees the old string. `setString` is the same.

When you output the address you want `post("address: %d", name)` not `post("address: %d", &this->name)` what you are printing is the address of `name` inside your object, not the address `name` is pointing to.

I have to agree with Cameron, `std::string` will save you from all this complexity.

Comment: Thanks John. I've made changes and I'm seeing more clearly. 
Something happens between when the Pd API framework is initialized and when I (later) call a function in that framework.

"name" is private, and I don't increment. ???

-------- in setString -----------
source: HELLOWORLD
length: 10

------- in pd_class_new------------
MULTIPLE CALLS TO postString....all produce this

copy: HELLOWORLD
length: 10
address: 32774028
address-2: 32578488

------- in pd_class_bang------------

MULTIPLE CALLS TO postString....all produce this
string: ELLOWORLD
length: 9
address: 32774028
address-2: 32578489

Comment: I've posted an edit above, as it's still not producing the expected behavior. Is there anything involving compiling or using shared libraries that would affect the memory being addressed in this way?

Comment: @PhilipMiller Your setString function is still wrong `this->name = new char[strlen(sourceString)];` should be `this->name = new char[strlen(sourceString) + 1];`. But something strange seems to be going on. I guess the code I'd need to see is the code when you communicate with your dll. You've got memory corruption of some kind as your `name` pointer is being incremented. But what the cause is I can't say at the moment.

Comment: John, I'll make the changes, and post an edit. In the meantime, do you know about data alignment in pointer allocation? Do you think this might have anything to do with it?
 
I'm thinking of compiling the entire package that I'm using, to try to fix any issues that may have come about because of compilation on another system. Thoughts?

Comment: @PhilipMiller Recompilation sounds like a good idea. It's perfectly possible that two compilers will layout the internals of a class differently. Although your recordString class is very simple I think? Anyway certainly can't do any harm.

Comment: Thanks again John. Closing this.